# Table cell padding does not work when it is hidden

Tags: css, css-tables

I have designed a table with hidden cell. When cell text will overflow then it will hidden with no ellipsis.If I do not use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` that time cell padding does not work, The problem is depicted below where yellow marked.
[image]

[Sample code](http://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/MypOap)

Comment: I'm checking up on older answers of mine and found one below. Wasn't the update useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated*

Here are 2 options, pseudo element or an extra div.

**Pseudo element**  (no change required in markup)

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grmopw

CSS

```
.users td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;           /* added prop. */
  background: inherit;          /* added prop. */
}
.users td:after {               /* added rule */
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background: inherit;
}

.users tr:nth-child(odd) {      /* added rule */
  background: white;
}
```

---

**Extra div**

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reyYEZ

CSS

```
.users td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.users td div {                /* added rule */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
  <tr>
    <td><div>00011111111111111111111</div></td>
    <td>Johnny Five</td>
    <td>Robotin'</td>
    <td><div>need@input.com</div></td>
    <td>0001</td>
    <td>Johnny Five</td>
    <td>Robotin'</td>
    <td><div>need@input.com</div></td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td><div>Super Superlonglastnamesmith</div></td>
    <td>Doin' stuff</td>
    <td><div>doing@stuff.com</div></td>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td><div>Super Superlonglastnamesmith</div></td>
    <td>Doin' stuff</td>
    <td><div>doing@stuff.com</div></td>        
  </tr>
```

---

***Side note***

The `text-overflow` property actually has a string option, though it is still only supported by Firefox

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqBYMz

CSS

```
.users td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '';
}
```

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the `table-layout` of class `.user` to `auto`. That should make the padding work as intended.

Comment: Hi, But column width is increased by text, no need column increased. column width width: 5% does not work

Answer (score -1):

Padding don't have color attribute,so we can't hide it by padding,but we can use border to carry out.

add this code to the CSS file

```
.users tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-of-type(4){
  border-right:15px solid #fff;
}
.users tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-of-type(4){
  border-right:15px solid lightblue;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RDIj.png)